# Weird ridges/wrinkles along iPhone model

Tags: artifacts

I'm new to Blender/3D design as a whole and I am getting some weird ridges in my models. I believe this happened when I beveled it. Any ideas as to what I can do smooth this out?

File: https://www.mediafire.com/file/kkr2q56rfd3x4qu/050323-Iphone.blend/file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faces of *Cube* and *Cube.012* are overlapping, you need to fix the problem by moving the object (or the mesh within the object) a bit on its Z axis:

[image]

Also you have overlapping vertices in *Cube.012*, you need to do a <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

And you have a lot of useless topology in *Cube*, it happened when you beveled the edge, you also beveled all these edges, which is useless and also created bad artefacts, I'm not sure how to easily dissolve these useless topology though:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! As a novice, this means a lot. I appreciate you looking into this for me!